# Checkbox / listview drama with PHP MySQL (Android application)

Tags: android, mysql, listview

As if combining checkbox and listview wasn't difficult enough. I've faced this stupid problem: " my list items are suppose to be downloaded from an HTTP request (done) but I don't know now where I should put the checkbox on the code so each list item has its own checkbox and how can I memorize each item was cheacked ". The following are the used code for the HTTP request:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PID= "name";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "category";
    /*private static final String TAG_UNIT = "unit";
    private static final String TAG_CALORY = "calory";
    private static final String TAG_CARBOHYDRATE = "carbohydrate";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "category";*/
    // the array was defined in PHP file
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        EditProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received 
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            Log.d("NUN complete","tyt");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading items. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... Args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID); // also name
                        String category = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY );
                        // NO NEED FOR THEM !!
                        /*
                        String unit = c.getString(TAG_UNIT );
                        String category = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY );
                        String calory = c.getString(TAG_CALORY );
                        String carbohydrate = c.getString(TAG_CARBOHYDRATE ); */


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, category);
                        //map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_CATEGORY},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.category});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter, where you put all items you got from your HTTP request. and a checkbox per each item, you can use [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) instead of `SimpleAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml with the `TextView` that you are using to display the products and a `CheckBox` then it will be generated for every item in your `list`. Just be sure to use a `ListView with the`android:id`

```
<ListView
android:id=@android:id/list
.../>
```

or you will get an error.

Also, you shouldn't need `runOnUiThread()` in `onPostExecute()` as it already runs on the `UI` thread